# Step change in input parameter with time in R

Tags: r, numerical-methods, pde

If anyone can help me how to incorporate `step` in input parameter with respect to time. Please see the code below:

```
library(ReacTran)

N <- 10   # No of grids
L = 0.10   # thickness, m
l = L/2    # Half of thickness, m

k= 0.412    # thermal conductivity, W/m-K
cp = 3530    # thermal conductivity, J/kg-K
rho = 1100   # density, kg/m3
T_int = 57.2       # Initial temperature , degC
T_air = 19        # air temperature, degC
h_air = 20        # Convective heat transfer coeff of air, W/m2-K

xgrid <- setup.grid.1D(x.up = 0, x.down = l, N = N)
x <- xgrid$x.mid

alpha.coeff <-  (k*3600)/(rho*cp)



Diffusion <- function (t, Y, parms){
  tran <- tran.1D(C=Y, flux.down = 0, C.up = T_air, a.bl.up = h_air,
                   D = alpha.coeff, dx = xgrid)
  list(dY = tran$dC, flux.up = tran$flux.up,
       flux.down = tran$flux.down)
}

# Initial condition
Yini <- rep(T_int, N)
times <- seq(from = 0, to = 2, by = 0.2)
print(system.time(
  out <- ode.1D(y = Yini, times = times, func = Diffusion,
               parms = NULL, dimens = N)))

plot(times, out[,(N+1)], type = "l", lwd = 2, xlab = "time, hr", ylab = "Temperature")
```

I want the `T_air` to be constant for the 1st hour and it changes to another value for remaining `1 hr`. This would be a `step change`in the parameter. How can I do it?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Soetaert, Cash and Mazzia's book "Solving Differential Equations in R" has a section at page 66 for modeling effects of heating when temperature crosses a particular threshold. It's part of section 3.4 Modeling Discontinuous Equations. I don't think a step change in temperature is particularly realistic. Have you considered a stepwise change in the rate of temp increase that was less than infinite?

Comment: Thanks, I will look at it. The physical process could be that system was exposed to air with certain temperature and held it for 1 hr and then suddenly exposed to another air that is maintained at a different temperature. It is like a heating and cooling process.